# Ocelot API Gateway inside Azure

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, ocelot

I'm trying to create working solution with Ocelot API Gateway. I managed to create working solution locally on my pc. Now I want to move to the next step which is to deploy this solution to Azure. 
As far as I know in order to do that I need one of those things :
-Docker host, in your local dev PC, on-premises or in the cloud
-Kubernetes cluster, on-premises or in managed cloud such as Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
-Service Fabric cluster, on-premises or in the cloud
-Service Fabric mesh, as PaaS/Serverless in Azure

I don't have much experience in any of those but I think the best one will be to use Docker App Service within Azure.

I'm working on deploying my projects but I believe I will need to create some Virtual Networks so those docker images will be able to communicate with each other. Maybe there is some tutorial online ? Or anybody has done something similar ? I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question, while certainly of value, is not a good fit for this website. StackOverflow is for helping with specific, detailed problems.  Questions about choosing an approach to deploy a complex system are not easy to answer, and it is unlikely therefore that you will receive helpful responses, beyond people's "opinions", which should never be blindly followed anyway.

Comment: I believe you've got my question wrong. I'm not asking about choosing approach ( I thinks I already have one) I'm asking how can make connection between docker container inside Azure